# Перетаскивание img и div

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

Есть код

```js
document.onmousedown = function(event) {
  var tar = event.target;
  if (tar.tagName != 'IMG' && tar.tagName != 'DIV') return;
  tar.style.position = 'absolute';
  document.onmousemove = function(event) {
    tar.style.left = event.pageX - 20 + 'px';
    tar.style.top = event.pageY - 20 + 'px';
  }
  tar.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = tar.onmouseup = null;
  }
  tar.ondragstart = function() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px
}
```

```html
<div style='background: blue; width:100px; height:100px'></div>
<img src="https://js.cx/drag-heroes/ball.png">
```

Если перетаскивать `img`, то он может выходить за пределы экрана, но прокрутку экрана не вызывает. Если перетаскивать `div` за пределы экрана, то он вызывает прокрутку. Проверила в Хроме и Лисе - работает одинаково.

Какое свойство объектов вызывает это различие?

Comment: Я установила img display:block, задала ему размеры, но он всё равно ведёт себя так же. Почему? Как сделать, чтобы появлялась прокрутка и при перетаскивании картинки?

Answer (score 3):

Свойство `overflow` родительского элемента (`body`) указывает, что случится, если содержимое выйдет за пределы этого контейнера.

Важно отметить, что свойство '`overflow`' действует только на **блочные** элементы с установленной высотой. В Вашем случае: `div` - блочный с установленной высотой, `img` - строчный элемент.

Источник: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Кстати, если установить `overflow: hidden` для тэга `body`, то в таком случае скролл не появится, если `div` выйдет за пределы экрана.

Comment: Можно так же заменить  в `tar.style.left` `event.pageX` на `event.clientX` , так не потеряется `<body style="height:2000px;">`

Comment: А причем тут скрыть скролл? Автор спрашивала, почему не скроллится страница, когда подводишь картинку. В отличие от дива.

Comment: Я установила img display:block, задала ему размеры, но он всё равно ведёт себя так же. Почему? Как сделать, чтобы появлялась прокрутка и при перетаскивании картинки?

Answer (score 0):

В случае, когда картинка подводится, скорее всего, это стандартное поведение браузеров для элементов, у которых контент может перетаскиваться (dragging): картинки, ссылки, выделенный текст. У этих элементов создается "аватар", который сам и двигается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если подвести этот "аватар" к низу страницы, то она будет скроллиься. Предположу, что бразуеры в таких случаях игнорят источники "аватаров", а работают только для самих "аватаров".
В случае с `div` происходит скролл, из-за того, что браузер предполагает, что там выделяемый контент. Поэтому когда зажимается кнопка мышки, он думает, что началось выделение. А при выделение страница всегд скроллится.
Это основано на моих предположениях. Я пока не нашел, чтобы такое поведение где-то было задокументировано.

Если не нужно, чтобы работал скролл при `div'е`, то можно просто отменить действия браузера:

```
document.onmousemove = function(event) {
    tar.style.left = event.pageX - 20 + 'px';
    tar.style.top = event.pageY - 20 + 'px';
    return false;
  }
```

Вот пример, можете увидеть, что для непустой ссылки действия такие же, как и для картинки.

```js
document.onmousedown = function(event) {
  var tar = event.target;
  if (tar.tagName != 'IMG' && tar.tagName != 'DIV' && tar.tagName != 'A') return;
  tar.style.position = 'absolute';
  document.onmousemove = function(event) {
    tar.style.left = event.pageX - 20 + 'px';
    tar.style.top = event.pageY - 20 + 'px';
    //return false;
  }
  tar.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = tar.onmouseup = null;
  }
  tar.ondragstart = function() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px
}
```

```html
<div style='background: blue; width:100px; height:100px'></div>
<img src="https://js.cx/drag-heroes/ball.png">
<a href="http://referencesource.microsoft.com/">Link</a>
<a>Empty link</a>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы